# Creating Route objects in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
class PathComponents extends React.Component{
...
render(){
var articlesPath = this.state.titles.map(function(val){
  return(
    <Route path={val} component={DataVisualizationBox}/>
  )
})
return(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Main}>
      <IndexRoute component={DataOverviewBox}/>
      <Route path="/" component={DataOverviewBox}/>
      <Route path="dataVis" component={DataVisualizationBox}/>
      <Route path="compare" component={DataComparison}/>
      <Route path="overallStats" component={DataBox}/>
      <Route path="dataCrawling" component={DataCrawlerBox}/>
      {articlesPath}
    </Route>
  </Router>
)
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<PathComponents/>, mainPage);
```

I have the above code ( Some parts are removed because they are irrelevant). I want to create routes to different article titles based on the articles i have in my database. However, I was met with the error message:

Warning: [react-router] Location "*some title*" did not match any routes.

Anybody know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Suppose you have 1000 articles you dont want to end up with 1000 routes

```
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Main}>
      <IndexRoute component={DataOverviewBox}/>
      <Route path="/" component={DataOverviewBox}/>
      <Route path="dataVis" component={DataVisualizationBox}/>
      <Route path="compare" component={DataComparison}/>
      <Route path="overallStats" component={DataBox}/>
      <Route path="dataCrawling" component={DataCrawlerBox}/>
      <Route path="/:article_title" component={ArticleViewer}/>
      {'add this route, also note this is absolute path'}
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

Inside `ArticleViewer` component you can do something like

```
var title = this.props.params.article_title;
//from this title extract your article somehow
```